# jQuery doesn't work | Wordpress top menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu

**Edit:** I got it working by... loading jquery library I thought jQuery works like JavaScript without the need to import anything. Sorry for wasting your time with a noobish question.

//

This is working wordpress plugin which uses jQuery to fix the displaying of top menu(hover effect) in IE6.

What I want is to implement the functionality in the theme while eliminating the need of plugin.

The error I was getting if I put this part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
     $('#access li').mouseover( function() {
     $(this).find('ul').show();
     });
     $('#access li').mouseleave( function() {
     $(this).find('ul').hide();
     });
     $('#access li ul').mouseleave( function() {
     $(this).hide();
     });
    });
    </script>
```

in the `<head>` section was `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` so I found out that most likely the problem is that my code is run before JS is loaded.

I used solution found on the web and wrapped my code in this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //my code here
});
```

And tried it out.Now I was getting two errors.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

After looking at the error it's more clear, but still not sure why isn't it working

//

I got it working by loading jquery library from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js I thought jQuery works like JavaScript without the need to import anything ;D

Wordpress plugin source code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Twentyten IE6 Menus
 * Author: Sara Cannon
 * Author URI: http://sara-cannon.com
 * Description: Make the menu drop down in IE6 (if you care about that sort of thing)
 * Version: 1.0
 * License: GPL2
 */
function sara_twentyten_ie6_menus_enqueue() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'sara_twentyten_ie6_menus_enqueue' );

function sara_twentyten_ie6_menus_script() {
?>
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
 $('#access li').mouseover( function() {
 $(this).find('ul').show();
 });
 $('#access li').mouseleave( function() {
 $(this).find('ul').hide();
 });
 $('#access li ul').mouseleave( function() {
 $(this).hide();
 });
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'sara_twentyten_ie6_menus_script' );
```

Comment: JS errors in firebug? Are you manually linking jQuery? This question is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery dont pass anything on .ready(function() {});

try this:

```
    (function($, window, document, undefined) {
       $(function() {
         $('#access li').mouseover( function() {
         $(this).find('ul').show();
         });
         $('#access li').mouseleave( function() {
         $(this).find('ul').hide();
         });
         $('#access li ul').mouseleave( function() {
         $(this).hide();
         });
       });
    })(jQuery, window, document);
```

Inside this block jQuery ($) should not be undefined if u imported jQuery correctly.